# Output a *.csv file created from a list of lists

Tags: csv, python-3.x

Firstly, I'm just learning Python (which is my first language) so, while I recognise there are numerous websites that address this, I've spent a weekend trying to get my head around implementing a solution and got nowhere with it. So, I'm hoping someone here can help me :)

The problem is simple: I've created a list of lists in a Python program, and I need to output them to a *.csv file so I can import it into Excel etc.

The list looks like this:

```
[['title1','title2','title3'],['date1','info1','category1'],['date2','info2','category3'],...]
```

I've found solutions where the elements in each list are integers, I can't get them to work with strings.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a CSV module that can do this:

```
import csv

data = [['title1','title2','title3'],['date1','info1','category1'],['date2','info2','category3']]

with open('stuff.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  for line in data:
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried the code, I get an error message `invalid mode: 'wv'` when I first implemented it, it seems to run 'error free' when I change it to just `'w'`. This might be a stupid question, but where exactly does the file output to? It's not clear to me from reading the documentation etc how you actually save the file to a location? Have I implemented your solution wrong or am I just missing something obvious? Thanks again for your help on this! Adam

Comment: Sorry, typo.  That was supposed to be `wb`.  The `w` is for write, and the `b` is for binary.  You don't really need the `b` flag for CSV files, and unless you're running on Windows, `b` doesn't do anything different anyway.

Comment: My example will write a file called `stuff.csv` to the current directory (wherever you are when you ran the script).  You can put a full file path in there, like `/home/adam/stuff.csv`.